# Async call to backendless data

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, backendless

This works, but it freezes the page during call:

```
  getAllNewEstate: function(callback) {
    function NewEstateData() {};
    var items = Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData ).find().data;
    callback(items)
  },
```

How can i make async call?

docs: 
http://backendless.com/documentation/data/js/data_sync_and_async_calls.htm
http://backendless.com/documentation/data/js/data_basic_search.htm

**updates**

**I tried:**

```
  getAllNewEstate: function(callback) {
    function NewEstateData() {};
    Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData ).find( function(e) {
        console.log('event', e);
        callback(e.data);
    });
  },
```

// no errors, no console.log,

```
  getAllNewEstate: function(callback) {
    Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData ).find( function(e) {
        console.log('event', e);
        callback(e.data);
    });
  },
```

// Uncaught ReferenceError: NewEstateData is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add callback for call find asynchronously:

```
getAllNewEstate: function(callback) {
    function NewEstateData() {};
    Backendless.Persistence.of( NewEstateData ).find( new Backendless.Async(
        function(e) {
             console.log(e);
             callback(e);
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: I've added answer in the description